# Excel 2010: deleting button only on copied sheet

Tags: excel, vba, templates, button, copy

It looks like an Excel bug: I want to copy an Excel worksheet and export it with a command button while deleting the command button on the copy with following code (not relevant code deleted):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
N = Sheets.Count
Sheets("XYZ").Copy After:=Sheets(N)
''''' Sheets("XYZ").Select   ''''' leads to an error - see below
Sheets(N + 1).Unprotect
Sheets(N + 1).Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets(N + 1).Move      ' creates and activates a new workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The problem is that the template should return to sheet "XYZ" with the button. However, whatever I tried (inclusively DoEvents and error trapping !), Excel always attempts to delete the same button on the protected template, too - leading to the error ("Command cannot be used in a protected sheet…").

The bug does NOT appear if any other sheet of the template is selected.
Note: as the template sometimes has hidden sheets, it is simpler to add the copied sheet as the last one, thus the template returns to its last sheet when moving the copied sheet.

It there any workaround for the template to return to the desired macro button's sheet "XYZ" without generating an error ?

Answer (score 0):

***My workbook "XYZ" is protected and this is the real cause for the bug.***

Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't see a significant difference, and indeed the error is still here though somewhat hidden: after the sub finishes, the focus is on the new workbook with sheet "XYZ (2)" and everything appears normal.

This is apparently still the case when one closes the new workbook and returns to the template (or workbook with macro) with focus on the last sheet. 
However, as soon as the template's workbook sheet "XYZ" is selected, the error message appears.

I have now looked stepwise and more in detail at the sub: the Shapes….Delete command obviously **plans** to delete the button simultaneously on both sheets "XYZ" and "XYZ (2)" – but fortunately deletes only the correct button on sheet "XYZ (2)" !
Thus, the problem's workaround surprisingly requires **temporarily unprotecting** the sheet on which nothing should be done (deep thinking, completely mad):

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Sheets.Count
    Sheets("XYZ").Copy After:=Sheets(N)
    Sheets("XYZ").Select
    With Sheets(N + 1)
        .Unprotect
      Sheets("XYZ").Unprotect    ' avoids the erroneous error message
        .Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Delete  ' Sheets(N+1) = "XYZ (2)"
      Sheets("XYZ").Protect _
          DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        .Move
    End With
End Sub
```

**Additional comment**:
To copy a sheet as really the last sheet as is desired here, it is necessary temporarily to change the former last sheet's property to visible if it is hidden. Otherwise Excel performs .Copy Before:= instead of .Copy After:= …
and then, Sheets(N+1) points to the wrong, hidden one – of course not to be moved and without the button to be deleted !